# Does nginx set Via header for proxied requests?

Tags: nginx

```
# server 1
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://server2/;
    }
}

# server 2
server {
    listen 80;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/css;

    location / {
        root /app;
    }
}
```

When i try to get a static file from server 2 directly, i get a gzipped file. When i try to get a static file from server 1, i get non-gzipped file, because nginx doesn't compress files for requests from proxy servers.

From docs:

> The fact that a request comes from a proxy server is determined by the presence of the Via header field in the request

i changed server 1 config to remove Via header

```
# server 1
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   "Via" "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://server2/;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I know i can use gzip_proxied but my questions are:

1. Does nginx set Via header for proxied requests and what value?
2. How can i debug and see what final headers does second server get?
3. Why removing Via header doesn't work and server 2 still knows that the request is from proxy server

Comment: 1) needs debugging  2) ... o , wait.... .... see: [serverfault.com: How can I debug nginx further than the error log?](https://serverfault.com/questions/433024/how-can-i-debug-nginx-further-than-the-error-log)